# Swift: Key Value Observing Collections

Tags: ios, swift, collections, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I've read the [Swift documentation on Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_8).

But, how do I implement key-value observing for collections in Swift?

Here's the relevant Object-C documentation that's missing for Swift:

- [Collection Accessor Patterns for To-Many Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB)
- [To-Many Relationship Key-Value Coding Compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-SW2)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class Document: NSDocument {

    var rooms = [Room]()

    func insertObject(room: Room, inRoomsAtIndex index: Int)
    {
        // Do something interesting 
        NSLog("Adding \(room) to \(rooms)")

        // Perform the actual insert
        rooms.insert(room, atIndex: index)
    }

    func removeObjectFromRoomsAtIndex(index: Int)
    {
        let room = rooms[index]
        NSLog("Removing room \(room)")


        // Perform the actual remove
       rooms.removeAtIndex(index)
    }

    // ...
}
```

I got to this by translating the expected Obj-C KV signatures to Swift for the methods I was interested in.  You should be able to get the others (for unordered to-many) working the same way.